# Silverlight 4 drag-drop not working in OOB mode (under SL5 RC)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop, silverlight-oob, silverlight-5.0

I added basic file drag drop to a Silverlight 4 OOB app and found it always gave the no-drop cursor.

If I turn off OOB mode on the same app and found drag drop of files works fine in the browser.

**Does anyone know why the requirements for file drag-drop may be different in OOB?**

### Followup:

I have now also tried the simple drag drop app from here: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/11/26/silverlight-4-s-new-drag-and-drop-support.aspx and when I switch it to OOB mode it also fails to drag drop.

**Note: Am am use the current RC of Silverlight 5, so it is probably a compatibility bug. I notice that half the new features on the Telerik Silverlight Demo site do not loaded under SL5 eother.*

Comment: I've had a quick play with Jeff Prosise's drag-and-drop application and I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Luke Woodward: There is a chance it is specific to the version of Silverlight I have installed (I currently have 5.0.60818.0 installed). Maybe it is not quite backward compatible?

Comment: Perhaps it's because Silverlight 5 is still an RC.  I'm using Silverlight 4.

Comment: Luke Woodward: I think it *will* be SL5... difficult to keep switching as I am doing SL5 development as well. I will change the tags to match.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the WindowLess parameter is set to false.

```
<param name="windowless" value="false" />
```